# Cannot Find symbol Java MultiDimensional Array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, compiler-errors

Simple program that asks the user about bus routes and some information about them. This then stores them in a 2-d array. And asks the user some questions. Ive only tried to code the decision to print the array out at the moment.

This error keeps popping up when I try to compile it.

```
Cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable routes
location: class question
```

Its for routes and for decisions

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class question {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[][] array = new String[4][2];
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("How many bus routes are there");
    routes = sc.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < routes ; i++) {
      System.out.println("Please enter the bus route");
      System.out.println("What is the bus route");
      array[i][0] = sc.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Start Location");
      array[i][1] = sc.nextLine();
      System.out.println("End Location");
      array[i][2] = sc.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Who is the driver for bus route " + i);
      array[i][3] = sc.nextLine();

}

    System.out.println("Do you want to 1) Print all bus routes 2) Start a new day 3) Quit ? ");
    decision = sc.nextInt();

    if (decision = 1) {
      for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array[i]));
    }

}
}
}
```

Comment: Where do you declare `routes`?

Comment: Where's 'routes' declaration?

Comment: I feel very foolish for missing something so basic thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to declare routes as int

```
 int routes = sc.nextInt();
```

same with decision

Also, use == in a condition to check equality

```
 if (decision == 1) {
```